# Cordova - what will happen if I run multiple time npm install -g cordova?

Tags: cordova

I have window 7 OS, through by cmd what will happen if I run multiple time **npm install -g cordova** ?

I am facing following error :- 
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-app-hello-world/-/cordo
va-app-hello-world-3.10.0.tgz

```html
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Sandy_PC>node --version
v4.3.0

C:\Users\Sandy_PC>npm unistall -g cordova

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, add-user, adduser, apihelp, author, bin, bugs, c,
    cache, completion, config, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag,
    dist-tags, docs, edit, explore, faq, find, find-dupes, get,
    help, help-search, home, i, info, init, install, issues, la,
    link, list, ll, ln, login, logout, ls, outdated, owner,
    pack, ping, prefix, prune, publish, r, rb, rebuild, remove,
    repo, restart, rm, root, run-script, s, se, search, set,
    show, shrinkwrap, star, stars, start, stop, t, tag, team,
    test, tst, un, uninstall, unlink, unpublish, unstar, up,
    update, upgrade, v, verison, version, view, whoami

npm <cmd> -h     quick help on <cmd>
npm -l           display full usage info
npm faq          commonly asked questions
npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\Sandy_PC\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@2.14.12 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm

C:\Users\Sandy_PC>npm install -g cordova
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-app-hello-world/-/cordo
va-app-hello-world-3.10.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 18
5.31.17.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-app-hello-world/-/cordo
va-app-hello-world-3.10.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 18
5.31.17.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-app-hello-world/-/cordo
va-app-hello-world-3.10.0.tgz
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v4.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 185.31.17.162:443
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 185.31.17.162:443]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '185.31.17.162',
npm ERR!   port: 443,
npm ERR!   parent: 'cordova-lib' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sandy_PC\npm-debug.log

C:\Users\Sandy_PC>
```

Comment: I want to know, is it's overwrite with latest version or it's create duplicate version of cordova?

Answer (score 1):

`npm install -g cordova` fetches whatever new version of cordova is available in the repo and installs it in your device replacing the previous version.
`npm update -g cordova` does the same thing. However, with the npm install, you get the choice of choosing the specific version.
eg: `npm install -g cordova@3.1.0-0.2.0` as such.

Comment: Incase you have problem with the updates, you can delete the .cordova that lies in the c://users/ folder, run npm unistall -g cordova and install the specific working version of cordova by running the command npm install -g cordova@3.1.0-0.2.0 as such.

Comment: I'm getting error - npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-app-hello-world/-/cordo
va-app-hello-world-3.10.0.tgz

Comment: Alex can you see my question again, I modify my question because I'm getting error while installing cordova. Don't know much more about proxy.

Comment: you should have asked another question for that, Anyway, the error is with your npm. Try installing new version of node.js and running the code again.

Comment: Alex today I install latest version of nodejs and after started installing cordova. In cmd I checked my version and it's showing as v4.3.0

Comment: After looking your codes, i found that you have a typo, npm uninstall -g cordova, you are missing a n in the command.